# Which direction need for INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql

If I check this example: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

This make sense:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```

but this would work? I do not think so, right?

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```

I should always do `child INNER JOIN parent` and never `parent INNER JOIN child`, right?

Comment: It is the same thing.  IOW not right, may be more readable and that is it.

Comment: Also it is up to backend to apply the join order, in some backends you can force the order of joins. Most people prefer writing parent INNER JOIN child.

Comment: an inner join is just all rows from the cross join where the join predicate evaluates to true. It makes no difference to the result of the cross join what order the tables are in, nor will that effect whether the join predicate evaluates to true or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the inner join in either order.  The only difference for an *inner* join is aesthetic.  The ordering doesn't event affect performance (because the database decides on the best execution path).

I do recommend table aliases either way:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, c.CustomerName
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN
     Orders o
     ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID;
```

Comment: What about LEFT JOIN? There I guess `child INNER JOIN parent` need, right?